# How to write trigger custom message error on Lead Object Unique Field

Tags: trigger

```
trigger PreventLeadDuplicate on Lead (before insert, before update){

    List<String> uniqueValueList = new List<String>();
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){

        uniqueValueList.add(l.UserName__c);
    }

    List<Lead> leadList = [select id, name, UserName__c from Lead where UserName__c IN :uniqueValueList];

    Map<String,Lead> uniqueValueMap = new Map<String,Lead>();
    for(Lead l : leadList){
        uniqueValueMap.put(l.UserName__c,l);        
    }

    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){
        if(uniqueValueMap.containsKey(l.UserName__c)){
            if(trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && l.id<>uniqueValueMap.get(l.UserName__c).id)){
                l.addError('An UserName of '+' '+leadList[0].UserName__c+ ' '+'already exists');
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want this code without soql query

Answer (score 2):

You should be using duplicate rules for this functionality. Otherwise, the only way to do this via trigger would be to query both `Lead` and `Contact`. I'm assuming that's what `Username__c` refers to. That having been said, there's also a flaw in your logic. Your final for loop should use the following entry criteria:

```
if((trigger.isBefore && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) 
    && l.id<>uniqueValueMap.get(l.UserName__c).id)){
```

Comment: UserName custom field which is created on Lead Object....

Comment: If it's a custom field on lead from say sites or a community, then no problem. In either case, you'll still want to query both lead and contact specifying `IsBefore && (isInsert || isUpdate)` trigger context along with the value already existing in your org.

Comment: I m doing this only on one object i.e. Lead

Comment: If you truly want to check for duplicates, you'll also query Contacts which you can do in a single query that checks for both. If you want to avoid the query, you'll need to move this to an AfterInsert/AfterUpdate trigger, but I'd expect the UserName__c to already exist in the Before/After Update context making it of low value in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add only string or exception message in addError().
Check the below links for more details:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError

If I look at your code,it looks like you are trying to avoid Duplicate records from saving in database.Correct me if I am wrong.

If yes then you can achieve the same requirement by creating duplicate rule on Lead Object.You do not need to go via Coding solution.

To create duplicate rule,you can go to Data Management-->Duplicate Management-->Duplicate Record Sets-->Duplicate Rules.

Let me know if it helps..

Comment: yes correct...but i need this code without using query on lead ...and one more thing i dont want to go with Duplicate Rules.....Anyways Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are not using SOQL query then How will you access Lead data related to UserName__c, So You have to use SOQL query for Existing records.
2. Either You can also Edit UserName__c Field and mark as a Unique Field i,e also send a error message regarding username already exist.

I Hope it will help you.

Regards,
Ajay